# Problema con reporte Jasper

Tags: mysql, jsp, jasper-reports

Estimados tengo un problema con jasper report
tengo unos reportes que hace una semana funcionaba, pero ahora ya no.
estos ahora al ejecutarlos desde jsp, se muestran en blanco o simplemente 
redireccionan a la misma pagina.Pero en la vista previa estos reportes se ven sin problemas.

**Reporte de Vuelos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código java del reporte de vuelos.

```
                                <%
                        try{
                        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
                        File reportFile=new File(application.getRealPath("reportes/reporteVuelosMasUsados2/reporteVuelosMasUsados2.jasper"));
                        Map parametros=new HashMap();


                        byte [] bytes= JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parametros,conn);
                        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

                        ServletOutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
                        //response.getOutputStream();
                        output.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        }
                        catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException ex)
                        {
                            ex.getMessage();
                        }
                    %>
```

El problema es que ahora al ejecutar el reporte, la vista me redirecciona al misma pagina y no al reporte y he compilado varias veces pero no muestra el reporte y no entiendo por que si antes si se podia.

acá imágenes del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá el código del botón

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="vistaReporteVuelos2.jsp" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Generar2</a>
```

por favor su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Algún mensaje en los logs de la consola del browser y/o el contenedor java?

Comment: Si compañero pero ya lo corregí gracias igual.

Comment: Disculpa , una consulta, como puedo cambiar el formato de la fecha del reporte?, ya que la consulta sql no tiene fecha y hora, pero el reporte siempre me muestra el campo fecha vuelo con fecha y hora y muestra siempre 12:00 AM . como puedo formatear esa fecha para que se muestre correctamente?

Comment: Con la propiedad *Pattern*.

Comment: y esa propiedad está en el entorno grafico de jasper report?

Comment: Sí, es una propiedad de Text Field.